least square regression of complex random variable
I have looked at some answers of how to calculate least square regression with a complex random variable. But I wonder following:

As a multivariate least square
regression, do we have to regard a multicollinearity between real and imaginary parts? If so, how can we address that issue?

As a multivariate least square regression, the least square with a complex random variable is always better than a single real variable because the complex number has a real and imaginary parts (i.e., like contains two variables)?

The inner product between two different complex variables is an analytic function?


